# AdMob Реклама не работает корректно

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-ee

Logcat[image: Logcat]Event Log[image: Event log]Добавляя тестовый ad unit ID(с офиц. сайта AdMob for Androids)(ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111), всё работает отлично, и тип эта реклама поздравляет меня, что я смог её разместить.
Но стоит мне поставить мой ad unit ID(моего приложения), ничего не появляется...
Вот собственно файлы и их коды:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="app.notruetester.ru.tets.MainActivity"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="313dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Отметь галочкой нужные квадраты"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.018"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Сгенерировать"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.964"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.641"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="229dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="206dp"
        android:text="Прописные русские буквы"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="123dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="122dp"
        android:text="Строчные русские буквы"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="123dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
        android:text="Спец. символы"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_width="256dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:text="Прописные английские буквы"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_width="248dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:text="Строчные английские буквы"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="122dp"
        android:text="Цифры"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="192dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="192dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.47945204"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="245dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="171dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="362dp"
        android:text="Здесь появится сгенрированный пароль"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="139dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:maxLength="20"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.638"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="365dp"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="XXXX"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.529"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="416dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package app.notruetester.ru.tets;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private AdView mAdView;
    TextView textView,textView2;
    Button button;
    EditText editText;
    CheckBox checkBox,checkBox2,checkBox3,checkBox4,checkBox5,checkBox6;
    AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    textView.setTextSize(20);
    editText.setText("2");
    checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    checkBox3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
    checkBox4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
    checkBox5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
    checkBox6 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox6);
   // AdView adView = AdView(this);
   // adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
   // adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "XXXX");
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}



public void onButtonClick(View view){
    if (!checkBox.isChecked() & !checkBox2.isChecked() & !checkBox3.isChecked() & !checkBox4.isChecked() & !checkBox5.isChecked() & !checkBox6.isChecked() ){
        checkBox3.setChecked(true);
        checkBox4.setChecked(true);
    }

    String pass  = "";
    Random r = new Random();
    int a= (editText.getText() == null)?0:Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
    int cntchars = a + r.nextInt(1);

    String values = "";
    if (checkBox.isChecked()){
        values += "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";}
    if (checkBox2.isChecked()){
        values += "!@#$%^&*()";}
    if (checkBox3.isChecked()){
        values += "0123456789";}
    if (checkBox4.isChecked()){
        values += "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";}
    if (checkBox5.isChecked()){
        values += "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";}
    if (checkBox6.isChecked()){
        values += "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";}

    int length = values.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
        Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int number = 0 + rnd.nextInt(length - 0 + 1);

        pass += (char)((r.nextInt(values.length())) + values.charAt(number));
    }


    textView2.setText(pass);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("")
            .setMessage("Сгенерированный пароль скопирован в буфер обмена")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton("ОК, понял, спасибо",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}


    }
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="app.notruetester.ru.tets">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"



    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />



                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Стате, если кто-то не понял и кому-то интересно, что за проект я пишу, то это генератор паролей(просто так, вдруг это как-то поможет)

### P.S. У рекламного баннера свойство visibility стоит как visible

Собственно сам вопрос:

Как заставить AdMob работать нормально?
Прошу помочь, буду очень благодарен, бьюсь уже второй день с этой проблей((

Больше LogCat'а:

```
08-31 13:00:40.311 2659-9883/app.notruetester.ru.tets D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 53K, 17% free 4793K/5752K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
08-31 13:00:40.315 2659-9883/app.notruetester.ru.tets W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services is missing.
08-31 13:00:40.315 2659-2659/app.notruetester.ru.tets W/Ads: The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
08-31 13:00:40.375 2659-2659/app.notruetester.ru.tets I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
08-31 13:00:40.375 2659-4529/app.notruetester.ru.tets W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
08-31 13:00:40.379 2659-2659/app.notruetester.ru.tets I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
08-31 13:00:40.379 2659-2659/app.notruetester.ru.tets D/webviewglue: nativeDestroy view: 0xb831b7f8
08-31 13:00:40.395 2659-2761/app.notruetester.ru.tets W/PicturePileLayerContent: Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
08-31 13:00:40.395 2659-2761/app.notruetester.ru.tets W/PicturePileLayerContent: Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
08-31 13:00:41.703 2659-2761/app.notruetester.ru.tets W/PicturePileLayerContent: Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
08-31 13:00:41.979 460-523/system_process D/MobileDataStateTracker: default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
08-31 13:01:40.379 2659-2659/app.notruetester.ru.tets I/Ads: Starting ad request.
08-31 13:01:40.379 2659-2659/app.notruetester.ru.tets I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
08-31 13:01:40.383 2659-10781/app.notruetester.ru.tets W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
08-31 13:01:40.383 2659-10781/app.notruetester.ru.tets W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
08-31 13:01:40.455 2659-10786/app.notruetester.ru.tets D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 822K, 18% free 4743K/5752K, paused 14ms, total 15ms
08-31 13:01:40.707 2659-10786/app.notruetester.ru.tets D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 768K, 18% free 4737K/5752K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
08-31 13:01:40.711 2659-10786/app.notruetester.ru.tets D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 36K, 17% free 4782K/5752K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
08-31 13:01:40.715 2659-10786/app.notruetester.ru.tets I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 4.879MB for 36886-byte allocation
08-31 13:01:40.715 2659-10786/app.notruetester.ru.tets D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 24K, 18% free 4794K/5792K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
08-31 13:01:40.723 2659-10786/app.notruetester.ru.tets W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services is missing.
08-31 13:01:40.723 2659-2659/app.notruetester.ru.tets W/Ads: The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
08-31 13:01:40.751 2659-2659/app.notruetester.ru.tets D/webviewglue: nativeDestroy view: 0xb84970c8
08-31 13:01:40.763 2659-2659/app.notruetester.ru.tets I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
08-31 13:01:40.763 2659-3635/app.notruetester.ru.tets W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
08-31 13:01:40.771 2659-2659/app.notruetester.ru.tets I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
08-31 13:01:40.787 2659-2761/app.notruetester.ru.tets W/PicturePileLayerContent: Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
08-31 13:01:40.787 2659-2761/app.notruetester.ru.tets W/PicturePileLayerContent: Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
08-31 13:01:41.827 2659-2761/app.notruetester.ru.tets W/PicturePileLayerContent: Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
08-31 13:01:41.999 460-523/system_process D/MobileDataStateTracker: default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
```

Comment: Покажите лог сервисов.

Comment: Приложил к вопросу, надеюсь правильно вас понял.

Comment: Правильно, но нужен весь лог, а не кусок. Стоит также учитывать, что если Вы только что создали баннер в AdMob, то он может появиться через некоторое время, но в любом случае ответ сервера в логе должен быть.

Comment: Надеюсь приложил достаточно большой кусок, ибо если прикреплять всё что там есть..... , не хватит места грубо говоря)

Comment: На счёт долго ожидания от сервера: Проверял - ждал, ждал около 15 минут(пологаю сервера Google не на столько медленные)

Comment: Проверьте на живом устройстве, а не эмуляторе. В логе есть сообщение об отсутствии Google Play сервисов, после которого весь модуль рекламы разрушается (что логично).

Comment: Хммм, ладно, сейчас тогда скину apk файл на гугл drive и от туда скачаю его на телефон, надеюсь такой путь действий не изменит последствия

Comment: Эхх.. Ничего... Как и в эмуляторе ничего (просто программа без рекламы, хоть Wi-fi работает)

Comment: Так напишите в поддержку,в чём проблема?)

Comment: Хммм, я ни разу такого не делал, но я так понимаю мне сразу не помогут, так что я здесь задаю вопросы) Или я что-то не так понял, мне могут сразу помочь?))

Comment: Лично я уже неделю жду, код ошибки 3. Не знаю что делать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы используете не то значение при инициализации `AdMob`. А именно - у вас в строке

> MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-8900900048721624/5809873614");

используется, видимо, `ID` баннера, а не `ID` приложения. Это 2 разных значения. Проверьте в настройках приложения в `AdMob` какое значение вам надо подставить при инициализации.

---

Также захардкоженные размеры баннера не ОК. Лучше поставить ширину во весь экран и высоту по содержимому.

---

Ну и выкладывать в общий доступ эти `ID` - плохая идея. Кто-то может их заюзать, накликать очень много с одного девайса и ваш акк заблокируют навсегда за накрутку и вы ничего не сможете доказать.

Comment: К сожалению, не могу проверить ваш ответ пока что(исправив одну ошибку, появилась другая....), но пологаю он правилен. Благодорю

Comment: + 
Размер баннера я исправил
+
ID Убрал, спасибо за совет)

Comment: Благодорю за ответ, в эмуляторе с моими ID всё работает, но на телефоне пока что нет. Пологаю гугл не будет давать рекламу пока нет пользователей.

Comment: Ахх, точно, я не предоставил платежные данные, из-за этого не показывается реклама)